# SQL Case Statement CASE calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, case

My CASE statement defaults to default zero result regardless of the two conditions. I am not sure what the problem is.

```
,CASE 
            WHEN [Contract]='INIM' THEN 'Index' 
            WHEN [Contract]='BANK' THEN 'Index' 
        ELSE 'Single' 
    END AS 'I/S'
,CASE 
            WHEN 'I/S'='Index' THEN ([Quantity] *[Spot Price]*10)/1000000
            WHEN 'I/S'='Single' THEN ([Quantity] *[Spot Price]*100)/1000000
        ELSE 0
END AS [Notional (ZARm)]
```

Comment: `'I/S'='Index'` that is **never** going to be true. The **literal string** `'I/S'` is never going to equal the literal string `'Index'`. This is like having `0 = 1` and expecting true.

Comment: Note you can't reference the column alias on the same level. You either wrapped the query in a CTE or derived table and you will have access to the alias on the outer query. Alternatively use `APPLY` to evaluate the expression

Comment: This is a reason not to use single quote (`'`) aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They only work when you define them, no where else; `ORDER BY 'value'` would *not* order by a column aliased as `'value'`, it would order by the `varchar` literal `'value'` (so would effectively not order at all). Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you *must* delimit identify them use the T-SQL identifier, brackets (`[]`), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (`"`).

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*. And sample data and desired results will always make a question easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `'I/S'` is a string literal, and not the alias `I/S`.  In any case, it is not possible to reuse this alias in the same `SELECT`.  Here is a corrected version:

```sql
CASE [Contract] WHEN 'INIM' THEN 'Index' 
                WHEN 'BANK' THEN 'Index' 
                ELSE 'Single' 
END AS [I/S],
CASE WHEN [Contract] IN ('INIM', 'BANK')
     THEN ([Quantity] *[Spot Price]*10) / 1000000
     ELSE ([Quantity] *[Spot Price]*100) / 1000000
END AS [Notional (ZARm)]
```

Note that, based on the first `CASE` expression, the `ELSE 0` of the second `CASE` expression will never occur.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I understand now. Thank you very much for you assistance.